# How Google maps API usage count works?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps distance matrix API with a single origin and multiple destinations from my android app.

The problem is, when I hit this api once, the usage count in Google Console increases by 3. I noticed that I was providing 3 destinations in the call. I changes the destination to 2 and 1, the usage count increased by 2 and 1 respectively. I was expecting that the usage count should increase with the number of hits and should not be dependent on the number of parameters in a call.

Is this normal? Is this how it works?

e.g.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.923700,77.647784&destinations=12.923942,77.647542|12.93452600,77.63034100|12.92798000,77.67424400&key=API_KEY
```

increases count by 3

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.923700,77.647784&destinations=12.923942,77.647542|12.93452600,77.63034100&key=API_KEY
```

increases count by 2

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.923700,77.647784&destinations=12.923942,77.647542&key=API_KEY
```

increases count by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal behavior. From Google [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits)

> Each query sent to the Google Maps Distance Matrix API is limited by
>   the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the
>   number of destinations defines the number of elements.